# jQuery UI specific use. Which .js to download?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-widget

I am looking to test Widgets -> Dialog -> Modal Confirmation.

**jquery-ui.js** is heavy to load just for a specific use.
From JQ UI site I downloaded a folder containing lots of small .js files

I guess they are part of the main js. I've tested to only load **jquery.ui.widget.js** and **jquery.ui.dialog.js** but I get this console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {       // The
>   jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
>         return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );     } has
>   no method 'widget'

Next codes are copy of the jQ UI sample from http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

***Sample displays and works as expected loading the heavy query-ui.js file only***

```
src="/js/jquery.ui.dialog.js"
src="/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"

$(function() {
      $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        width:350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Accept": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          },
          "Refuse": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Select your option</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML markup that references the jquery.ui.dialog.js and the JavaScript code that initialize the wdiget.

Comment: OK, I'll add that to the question. It is just the sample provided by jq-UI thats works good if I load the complete set from query-hi.js.  There's something missing but I don't realize what it is.
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to use and download the files which are necessary for the `dialog` widget visit the [jQuery UI Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Uncheck the "Toggle all" checkbox and only check **Widgets** -> **Dialog**. Each other file which is necessary gets checked automatically. The according link is [this](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=1111101000010100000000000000000000) one. Note that you can change the `CSS` configuration at the bottom of the page above the download button.

The downloaded `.zip` should contain 3 folders

> js
>
> development-bundle
>
> css

The important one is the `js` folder which includes a jQuery version (no UI without jQuery) and your customized jQuery UI `.js` files. One in readable form, one minified.
If you open the `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js` file you can see what it includes. In your case this should be:

> jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.ui.mouse.js, jquery.ui.position.js, jquery.ui.draggable.js, jquery.ui.resizable.js, jquery.ui.button.js, jquery.ui.dialog.js

I hope I got your question right and this is what you want.

Comment: The current wizard does not generate a file with a js folder. :(

Comment: Indeed! Instead the file you're most likely looking for is located in the root of the zip archive. It is named jquery-ui.js